# Android - close popUp window

Tags: android

I have a listView inside a popUp window and I want that when the user clicks on an item in the listview, the popUp window will automatically close. Any idea how I can do that?

```
  public void popUp(){
        final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(Record.this);

        final View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.input_language, null);
        final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Record.this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);

        String[] languages = {"Arabic","Bulgarian","Catalan"};

        ListView list = (ListView) promptView.findViewById(R.id.inputlang);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, languages);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                    long id) {

                String from_language = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), from_language, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // CLOSE POPUP WINDOW
            }
        });

        // setup a dialog window
        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

        // create an alert dialog
        AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by changing the order of initialization of the dialog:

```
public void popUp(){
    final ListView promptView = new ListView(this);
    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);
    // setup a dialog window
    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

    // create an alert dialog
    final AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    String[] languages = {"Arabic","Bulgarian","Catalan"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, languages);
    promptView.setAdapter(adapter);

    promptView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {

            String from_language = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), from_language, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // CLOSE POPUP WINDOW
            alert.dismiss();
        }
    });

    alert.show();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Put this code after `alert.show();`

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                    long id) {

                String from_language = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), from_language, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // CLOSE POPUP WINDOW
alert.dismiss();
            }
        });
```